# how to remove object from array in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

this is my code can un help with it how to write slice function properly

```
 export default function(state={inputs:[ ]}, action) {
        console.log(action.index);
        switch (action.type) {
        case APPEND_INPUT:
            return { ...state, inputs: state.inputs.concat({value:"",key:"1",type:'input'})};
        case APPEND_TEXTAREA:
            return { ...state, inputs: state.inputs.concat({value:"",key:"",type:'textarea'})};
        case APPEND_EMAIL:
            return { ...state, inputs: state.inputs.concat({value:"",key:"",type:'email'})};
        case REMOVE_INPUT:
            return  {inputs: state.inputs.slice(0)};

        default:
            return state;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Or:

```
{inputs: state.inputs.filter((_, i) => i !== action.index))
```

Answer (score 3):

Slice the array up to the index, and concat it to the slice from the index + 1 onwards:

```
{ 
    inputs: state.inputs.slice(0, action.index).concat(state.inputs.slice(action.index + 1))
}
```

If you use ES6 you can do this instead of concat:

```
{ 
    inputs: [...state.inputs.slice(0, action.index), ...state.inputs.slice(action.index + 1)]
}
```

Comment: it isn't working onclick its going to default state can u please help me with it